# How to receive feedback from systemctl?

Tags: systemd

I am missing a bit of feedback from systemd commands. After issuing a

```
systemctl restart my_service
```

there is no output and to receive confirmation if `my_service` is started, I need type

```
systemctl status my_service
```

Is there a way to have at least a line explaing what systemd did, and maybe also if service failed to start or was successful?

Comment: Like most other Unix-like utilities, you only get output if something went wrong. No output means it was successful.

Comment: You may also check `systemctl` return value, which will be non zero if any error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of commands and launch something like:

```
$ systemctl start my_service && journalctl -feu my_service
```

You get the last log lines for `my_service` and you need to press Ctrl+C for exiting.

I know, you asked for one command not two, sorry. But you can build your own command to wrap the two.